# sbt test task is failing in IDE

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I am trying to run the test sbt task using my IDE but I am getting the following error:

```
Compiling 12 Scala sources to 

/home/user/newPrs/projectname/processing/target/scala-2.11/test-classes...
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last test:copyResources for the full output.
[error] (test:copyResources) java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/user/newPrs/projectname/processing/target/scala-2.11/test-classes/rawData/data.parquet (Permission denied)
```

Any idea how to fix this please?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you run `ls -la /home/user/newPrs/projectname/processing/target/scala-2.11/test-classes/rawData/` in your console? Also check if file `data.parquet` is opened anywhere.

Comment: It seems like this file `/home/user/newPrs/projectname/processing/target/scala-2.11/test-classes/rawData/data.parquet` is not copied with the build process. Try looking into this location to see if file actually exists.